# Regressing, analysing data with points rather than polynomial?

Tags: regression, anova, generalized-linear-model, fitting

I am looking into making a regression of a bunch of data that is contained on some range of real numbers. In my case, x is between 0 and 1 and y is between 0 and 10. If I have 150 data points on this plane, and want to best model the original data with N data points (not polynomial, just points), how can I do this? How can I then analyse how good the fit is? Any help is appreciated. Sorry if my notation is not perfect, I am from a physics background so please bear with me. Cheers.

Data example:

```
x.vector <- cumsum(rnorm(150)^2) y.vector <- 10*rnorm(150)^2
```

I want to fit 2 points, 3, 4, ... and check fit at each one.

Comment: what do you mean by "model the data with points"?

Comment: Good question. If I wish to sample something with ~1000 points (the 150 is just for this example, doesnt matter as long as points >> output model points) and best represent it with points that can be linearly interpolated and that represent the underlying process. Intuitively/visually , I think this means minimizing some sort of error function, like square of difference from model point, but with few model points and many points in actual data, I am not sure what is best way to represent.

Comment: To be clear however, I would like to select (X,Y) pairs that best 'ftt' the data, meaning they do not have to be spaced in anyway but can be anywhere on the plane of 0 to 1 and 0 to 10.

Comment: So essentially you want to fit a piecewise linear function to the data? I.e., have intervals $(x_0,x_1), (x_1,x_2), \ldots, (x_{N-1},x_N)$ such that it is linear in each interval but the slope changes at each boundary?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (along with assessing some metric of 'error' produced by this fit -- presumably one that is statistically sound/supported by common practice!).

Comment: Also, I would strongly prefer to perform this analysis in R language, as my co-researchers are using it. So optimally perform in a manner that has associated packages/functions.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this in R is to use the `bs` (B-spline) function. Specifying a degree of 1 makes it piecewise linear. Here's an example, using different data since in your example, there's no dependence between x and y.

Generate some reproducible data

```
> set.seed(1234)
> x <- runif(150, -2, 3)
> y <- 7 * pnorm(x, 1, 0.7)^2 + rnorm(150, 0, .15)
```

Set up points where you want the slope to change

```
> knots <- c(-1,0,1,2)  # interior ones only
```

Fit a model and plot the fitted values

```
> piecel.lm <- lm(y ~ bs(x, degree = 1, knots = knots, Boundary.knots = c(-2,3)))
> plot(x, predict(piecel.lm))
```

[image: piecewise-linear predictions]

(This shows that it is indeed piecewise linear. But to get it in more useful form, just figure out the abscissae and ordinates at the knots (including the end ones):

```
> absc <- (-2):3
> ord <- predict(piecel.lm, newdata = data.frame(x = absc))
> plot(y ~ x)
> lines(ord ~ absc, col = "red")
> points(ord ~ absc, col = "red")
```

[image: data and piecewise-linear fit]

#### Additional comment:

If your goal is simply to have something that'll fit the data better than a polynomial, I'd suggest a natural cubic spline, which you can get in much the same was using the `ns` function. You can evaluate it at any $x$ value using the `predict` function with `newdata`. Here is the natural spline fit to these data, using the same knots:

```
> spline.lm <- lm(y ~ ns(x, knots = knots, Boundary.knots = c(-2,3)))
> plot(y ~ x)
> xnew <- seq(-2, 3, by = .2)
> lines(xnew, predict(spline.lm, newdata = data.frame(x = xnew)), col = "red")
```

[image: data and spline fit]

Comment: PS it is just a regression model, so you get the usual fit statistics - residuals, $MS_E$, $R^2$, etc.

Comment: @VaishakId -- I spent some time preparing an answer. Is it useful to you? Any comments?